# How to make Intellij Idea mark files, not tracked by Git?

Tags: git, version-control, intellij-idea

I've been using Git with Eclipse for a long time and now I'm switching to Intellij Idea.

In Eclipse, when you add a file to a source tree version-controlled by Git, that file is marked in the project tree. In that way you can always see what files are not added to Git.

How can I do the same (mark files, which are not tracked in Git yet) in Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually marks if you enable VCS integration. Here is below an example from Android Studio which is based on IntelliJ Idea so I suppose this behavior is the same for both. In the example the file .gitignore has been modified and it is highlighted with blue. File asd.txt is untracked and highlighted with red. File build.gradle is tracked and not modified.

[image: Android Studio Git Integration]